# Adding radiobuttons and ratingview in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, radio-button, rate

In a foor loop I need to create an item depending on an obj value:

for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<mylist.count;i++)
if(mylist[i].type==1)
{
//create radiobutton
}
else if(mylist[i].type==2)
{
//create ratingview
}
```

and so on

If more than one radiobutton is created in C#, how can I differentiate between the radiobuttons and the ratingviews? 
Like how can I put a tag or id for each item is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

If you can't find a tag property, just create one:

```
public void test() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (i<5)
        {
            //create radiobutton
            radiobutton btn = new radiobutton
            {
                Text = "Click to Rotate Text!",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                tag = i
            };

            Console.WriteLine(btn.tag);
        }
        else if (i > 2)
        {
            //create ratingview

        }
}

public class radiobutton : Button
{

    public int tag;
}
```